# Using CSharpSyntaxRewriter to convert System.String to string

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm working on a Roslyn CSharpSyntaxRewriter. Is there a simple way convert types to their type alias?

E.g.

`public System.String Property { get; set; }`

becomes:

`public string Property { get; set; }`

I clearly don't fully understand how to juggle types in Roslyn - I have had nothing but grief moving between `Type`, `ITypeSymbol` and `TypeSyntax`. Any wise words of the topic will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that there is actually an analyzer that ships with VS, and Roslyn that does this, sort of. It's [IDE0001](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/a4e375b95953e471660e9686a46893c97db70b0e/src/Features/Core/Portable/Diagnostics/Analyzers/IDEDiagnosticIds.cs#L7), and the analyzer is here: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features/Diagnostics/Analyzers/CSharpSimplifyTypeNamesDiagnosticAnalyzer.cs,99.

Comment: BTW The guy that edited the question also has a repo with an analyzer that does this: https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/9bc50e90383e006456e754d1e94573fbe43b2eb8/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/Diagnostics/General/UseAliasesInsteadOfConcreteType/UseAliasesInsteadOfConcreteTypeAnalyzer.cs. But maybe, you can actually use the `Simplifier` for this (issue [#269](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/issues/269), also in his repo).